# NoMethodError: undefined method `edit_detailed_reservation_path' while running unit/application_helper_test.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, minitest, rails-3-upgrade

We are migrating `2.3.18` application to `3.2.x`. We are facing an issue while running a test where it is not able to find routes using route helpers

Here is the assertion where we are facing issue

```
#test/unit/application_helper_test.rb
def test_calendar_link_to_with_named_route
  . . .
  calendar_link_to(31, date, {:named_route => 'edit_detailed_reservation_path', :method => :post})
  . . .
end
```

Here is how the method is defined in `ApplicationHelper`

```
def calendar_link_to(anchor_text, date, *args)
  options = args.first.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
  method = options[:method]
  named_route = options[:named_route]

  url_hash = { :day => date.day, :month => date.month, :year => date.year }
  url = named_route ? self.send(named_route, url_hash) : url_hash

  link_options = { :id => "date-#{date.year}-#{date.month}-#{date.day}" }
  if date > Parameter.event_horizon
    link_options[:title] = 'This date is beyond the event horizon.'
  end
  link_options[:method] = method if method
  link_to(anchor_text, url, link_options)
end
```

While running the test we get following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `edit_detailed_reservation_path'
```

To resolve this error I have also tried to put the below line inside application_helper.rb

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

We use below command to run the test

```
rake test TEST=test/unit/application_helper_test.rb
```

In Rails 2, `edit_detailed_reservation_path` gives absolute URL while inspecting it in a pry session but same doesn't work in Rails 3.

Would anybody please guide us what could be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: You have used route as string. 
You can try with this: 
`calendar_link_to(31, date, {:named_route => edit_detailed_reservation_path, :method => :post})

Comment: we try this, but still same error occurs.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue..did you get any solution for it? Means for helper method tests which contains routes or link_to kind of helper methods not able to access.